# Response PDF download from base64string c#

Tags: c#, pdf, memorystream

I'm trying to do an API for downloading PDF, what I did is like so:

```
HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage();
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
try {
    var base64 = "...";
    byte[] pdfBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

    stream = new MemoryStream(pdfBytes);

    var resultPDF = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());

    result.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    result.Content = new StringContent(resultPDF);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "BuildingDetail.pdf" };

} catch (Exception e) {
    stream.Close();
    result.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    result.ReasonPhrase = e.Message;// "Error occured while exporting csv file!";
} finally {
    stream.Close();
}
```

When I trying to test the API out, it able to download, but PDF is empty.

I also tried to copy the `base64` string and decode it by other free source `decode and download` website it seems working fine, so makes the `base64` is not the issue.

Any advice to this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use ByteArrayContent:

```
HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage();
try 
{
    byte[] pdfBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pdfLocation);
    result.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(pdfBytes );
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "BuildingDetail.pdf" };

} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    result.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    result.ReasonPhrase = e.Message;// "Error occured while exporting csv file!";
}
```